# JSON Loop array that is a value of an object

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I have a JavaScript object `{}` with a bunch of values, one of the values is an array `[]`. After converting to JSON will look something like this.

```
{
  "header-name": "",
  "header-role": "",
  "header-phone": "",
  "header-website": "",
  "header-email": "",
  "header-location": "",
  "exp-one": "ssfsdf",
  "exp-two": "sdfsdf",
  "exp-three": "",
  "exp-four": "",
  "exp-five": "",
  "exp-six": "",
  "exp-sub": [
    "1",
    "2",
    "3",
    "4",
    "5"
  ]
}
```

I am able to loop through the JSON using `var result = $.parseJSON(data); $.each(result, function(k, v) {});`

What i am trying to do is also loop over that array that sits in the object `"exp-sub"`, something like.

```
$.each(result, function(k, v) {
    if (v == "exp-sub"){
        $.each(k, function(key, val) {
            //loop over array, this doesn't work though
        }
    }
});
```

Have tried with a for loop also but does not work either, any help will be appreciated thanks.

Comment: try `if (k == "exp-sub")` instead of `if (v == "exp-sub")`

Comment: oops, the question was already answered! never mind

Comment: Was a typo, i was doing K and not V, problem solved below, thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually `k` is key i.e.**exp-sub** so you have to compare `k` and iterate over `v`

```js
var result={"header-name":"","header-role":"","header-phone":"","header-website":"","header-email":"","header-location":"","exp-one":"ssfsdf","exp-two":"sdfsdf","exp-three":"","exp-four":"","exp-five":"","exp-six":"","exp-sub":["1","2","3","4","5"]}

$.each(result, function(k, v) {
    //console.log(k, v)
    if (k == "exp-sub"){
      $.each(v, function(index, val) {
       console.log(val)
}); 
    }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Oh, loop the values of the array, not the key. Now i feel dumb, thank you.